# content of NSData into NSArray/NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, nsarray

I have this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xyz.com/ios/responseScript.php"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:&error];

    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


}
```

When I print the dataString, it shows exactly what I expect i.e.

> ["Bannana","Apple","SomeCheese"]

I want to process this into NSMutableArray. How can I do that?

Thanks,

Comment: At this stage you're looking to convert an NSString into the NSMutableArray. Have you tried componentsSeparatedbyString or Regex?

Comment: Nope I didn't because that sounds like over complicating stuff. any better ideas?

Comment: Umm.. removing the first and last characters (the "[" and "]") and then splitting the string into an array using componentsSeparatedbyString is overcomplicating stuff?

Comment: the code supplied by @edzio27 worked. simple and clean. Thanks though, may use it sometime later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSString *key in dictionary) {
    [array addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:key]];
}
```